# Limiting graph serialization depth for composite models in Tensorflow2.x

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am building a model generator in TF2.x, that composes models by putting together assemblies of simpler modules. When exporting such a model, I noticed that all component modules (submodules/sugraphs) are serialized and exported as well and are available at the load time, so if my model is composed of say P, Q the graph for P and Q is also serialized and same for all the children of P and Q.

My understanding is that the top-level graph is self-contained and does not need the graph structures of submodules, exporting them is wasteful if I only need to run the compute function at the top-level graph.

Is there a way I could achieve resource restriction using  tf.saved_model.save; I only mean to save and work with top level graphs. Ideally, I think it would be great to be able to provide a maximum depth at which the graph serialization/export is done so it excludes everything below this depth.

Any guidance on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

see the code snippet and the comments for more information, the code demonstrates that a composite model takes considerably more disk space than an equivalent monolithic model, did not look into memory and compute performance as yet...
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FeP_bhVwQ223A9GGts1v--FgXDNeb6jY?usp=sharing

Github gist:
https://gist.github.com/RameezI/3d51ab59d745d08b62daec77a3a5439c